# What are current_user_can () function parameters?

Tags: wordpress

What are `current_user_can()` function parameters ?

This function is used in wordpress script, I know a parameter called `publish_posts` , I want to know the other parameters .

There is a sample code :

```
if( current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) ) {
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/post-form.php';
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be a complete list:

[Roles and Capabilities - Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities)

Answer (score 1):

You can find these on the WordPress [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) page.

You can use any role or capability as an argument to the current_user_can() function.  Look in the contents on the right side of that page - the roles and capabilities (which are all usable) are all listed.